# Order list based on first two numbers in the string - .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

So I have 10 listboxes and one openfiledialog. I use the "Add" button to open a .txt file and sort every line in that file to the different listboxes depending on the string it contains.

Here are three lines from the .txt file:

```
Decent Cracker.crc, 2.0, 75 MB: 25.61.221.29
Generic Hasher.hash, 1.9, 63 MB: 25.61.221.29
Basic Port Scan.scan, 1.0, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29
```

Listbox 1 takes .crc strings, Listbox 2 takes .hash strings, and etc...

I have no problem filtering the files to their proper listboxes based on their extension, but what I would like to do now is sort each listbox based on descending version number (the number after the extension but before the size: ex 1.0).

I have tried the following code but it obviously failed.

```
'sort by first number
    Dim items = (From item In ListBox1.Items
                 Let parts = item.ToString.Split(New String() {" - ("}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                 Order By CInt(parts(0))
                 Select item).ToArray
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the `item` string look like?

Comment: I fail to see where is in your string the separator " - (" used in the Split method

Comment: @DonBoitnott The three line I provided as examples are each items.

Comment: @Steve Ahh yes, I have fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Module Module1
    Public Class RowComparer
        Implements IComparer(Of String)

        Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
            Dim xCodeParts As String() = x.Split(","c)(1).Trim.Split("."c) ' something like 1.1
            Dim yCodeParts As String() = y.Split(","c)(1).Trim.Split("."c) ' something like 1.20

            Dim xCodeText As String = ""
            Dim yCodeText As String = ""

            For i As Integer = 0 To xCodeParts.Length - 1
                xCodeParts(i) = xCodeParts(i).PadLeft(10, "0"c)
                xCodeText &= String.Format("|{0}|", xCodeParts(i))
            Next
            ' xCodeText is something like |0000000001||0000000001|

            For i As Integer = 0 To yCodeParts.Length - 1
                yCodeParts(i) = yCodeParts(i).PadLeft(10, "0"c)
                yCodeText &= String.Format("|{0}|", yCodeParts(i))
            Next
            ' yCodeText is something like |0000000001||0000000020|

            Return -xCodeText.CompareTo(yCodeText) ' - for desc order    
        End Function
    End Class


    Sub Main()
        Dim list As New List(Of String)({
                                        "Decent Cracker.crc, 1.1, 75 MB: 25.61.221.29",
                                        "Generic Hasher.hash, 1.20, 63 MB: 25.61.221.29",
                                        "Basic Port Scan.scan, 1.10, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29",
                                        "Basyyyyyyyyy.scan, 2.10, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29",
                                        "BasixxxxScan.scan, 1.12, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29"})

        list.Sort(New RowComparer)
        list.ForEach(Sub(value) Console.WriteLine(value))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

'Result
'Basyyyyyyyyy.scan, 2.10, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29
'Generic Hasher.hash, 1.20, 63 MB: 25.61.221.29
'BasixxxxScan.scan, 1.12, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29
'Basic Port Scan.scan, 1.10, 23 MB: 25.61.221.29
'Decent Cracker.crc, 1.1, 75 MB: 25.61.221.29

End Module
```

**EDIT**

```
Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Trial\list.txt")
Dim list as new List(Of String)(lines)
list.Sort(New RowComparer)
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I implement that into my project? Sorry i'm sort of a noob at this.

Comment: 1. I would get the rows from the files. 2. I would populate a List(Of string) and sort it. 3. I would add the list to the listbox by `listbox.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray)`

Comment: Yes I understand what the code is doing, I just don't understand how to insert this module into my project. Is it just in my form1.vb code?

Comment: Copy the `Class RowComparer` in your file but under of the `Class Fomr1` so in the file you have two classes.

Comment: You can also add a module to your project -named something like HelperModule- and add the class in this module. This module could function as a "repository" of common things for all the project.

Comment: thank you for that. Worked marvelously. The problem is that i'm loading a .txt file with all the strings into a listbox (listbox10) and then running the code you gave me by button click. Do I need a code to loop through the listbox and repeat the step every time? What I tried:  `Dim list As New List(Of String)(ListBox10.Items)`

Comment: Doing so you populate the listbox two times. Get the strings from the .txt file, add them to a list, sort the list and then populate the listbox from the list. Done. ;-)

Comment: I'm getting the strings and adding them to a listbox called listbox10. The problem is that with the sorting code that you gave me, the strings have to be in the code (as you can see in the example you've given us). The problem is I have thousands of lines I want to run so I can't just paste them all in the code, which is why I tried adapting the code you gave me so that `Dim list As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Trial\list.txt))` but that failed. This stops me from populating the listbox twice, but it is not working.

Comment: This should work Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Trial\list.txt")        Dim list As New List(Of String)(lines)

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Marked your input as the answer.

Comment: Glad we made it. :-D